# Prevent Django from prepending domain to beginning of URLs in RSS feeds

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm creating an RSS feed that contains application links for the URLs, but Django is prepending the domain name to any link that doesn't begin with *http*. So, URLs that should be *itunes://* are ending up as *http://example.comitunes://...*

**Update:**
Because I'm not building the feed based on a model, I'm using the following in the Feed class to create the links. I've verified that they are exactly as they should be when passed to item_link(), but Django appends *http://example.com* to the front of every link that doesn't begin with *http*:

```
def item_link(self, item):
  return item['url']
```

if link is *http://foo.com/some_external_domain/*, there's no problem.
if link is *itunes://some_itunes_store_link*, Django turns that into *http://example.comitunes://some_itunes_store_link*

The domain name is correct. That's not the problem. The problem is that I can't have the domain name prepended to an application link without breaking that link. I can't figure out how to tell Django to stop correcting links that don't need to be corrected.

Comment: Maybe check your sites in admin?

Comment: I don't even have the sites option in admin. But if I did, wouldn't changing it affect other parts of the site that rely on it? I just need to keep Django from trying to correct feed urls that shouldn't be "corrected."

Comment: Can you show us some code? Could be you don't have a good link attribute set?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in Django.

According to Django's [feed documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/syndication/#urls):

> If link doesn’t return the domain, the syndication framework will
>   insert the domain of the current site, according to your SITE_ID
>   setting.

My solution was to just build the entire RSS feed manually as a template. It's an unfortunate solution for what should be a simple option in Django feeds, but it works.